# Spork causes ActiveRecord to use nested transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, spork, minitest

I'm testing my Rails app using Minitest and Spork. Without spork everything works fine, each test gets rolled back in the database using savepoints. When I activate spork this behavior changes, it starts using nested transactioons (which are not supported in sqlite), and everything breaks down. Why does spork do this, and how can I stop it?

**Update:** When using spork, there are two levels of nested transactions. One is from activerecord (in my application), and one is added by minitest / spork / whatever around the whole test case. When I run it without spork only the outer transaction is added, and the inner ones are done using savepoints.

Comment: Ah ok .. sorry I assumed spork and minitest are causing the problems.. I'll remove my answer :(

Comment: Why are you using SQlite? I had the same problem and switched to Postgres. Now it's fine.